# SVG animation delay

Tags: html, animation, svg, vector, delay

**The Requirement**: I have some trouble with delay setting to each animation.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxJXvZ

But logic is different. Each line must be filled by blue color, one by one.

If I set the begin attribute, it completely crashes any animation rule

Here is my **CODE**:

```
<linearGradient id="first">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#4caddb">
    <animate id="anima1" begin="anima2.end" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</stop>
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#E1E1E1">
    <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</stop>
</linearGradient>
```

And

```
<linearGradient id="third">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#E1E1E1">
    <animate id="anima2" dur="1s" begin="anima1.end" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="1" to="0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</stop>
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#4caddb">
    <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="1" to="0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</stop>
</linearGradient>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

An animation with `repeatCount="indefinite"` has no end, so your referencing animation never starts. Use `begin="anima1.repeat"` instead. This event is raised each time the referenced animation starts anew.